# Using node modules in zeit/next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I have simple application on isomorphic react (zeit/next.js https://github.com/zeit/next.js).
How can I use node modules on server side?

Code example:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class extends React.Component {
        static async getInitialProps({ req }) {
            const isServer = !!req;
            if (isServer){
                // how!?
            }
            return {
                isServer: isServer
            }
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>test</div>
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: can your be more precise on what your problem is? you can do pretty much anything just where you placed the  "how!?" comment. if your code reaches this line, the react component is created by the server and you can require and call all node module has to offer...

Answer (score 1):

you also may want to use a custom server.js to send some data from the server in the request object.

like

```js
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const { readFileSync } = require('fs')
const next = require('next')
const mobxReact = require('mobx-react')
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

mobxReact.useStaticRendering(true)

app.prepare()
  .then(() => {
    createServer((req, res) => {
      const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
      req.rules = JSON.parse(readFileSync('./micro/rules.json', 'utf8')).rules
      handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
    })
      .listen(3000, err => {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log('> Ready')
      })
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can normally install your npm package

```
npm install <name package>
```

And use in your code

```
import <Componente of package> from '<name package>'
```

I hope that help!